# Getting source code from .apk file in android

Tags: android

**How we get the complete source code from .apk file .we also try try dex2jar and other process but we din't get the complete source code . and commented code is not shown .
**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file?rq=1

Comment: Try http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=873466

Answer (score 0):

Most of the developers use a thing called **proguard** which will be used for the `obfuscation of the code`, obfuscation generally means `making the code unreadable so to make the apk resist to any reverse engineering attempt`(resist here does not mean it can't be reverse engineered, if the apk has gone through the reverse engineered process , the person who attempted may not able to read the actual code the developer has written), i once tried to do reverse engineer the apk,ended up in the middle languages like `smali` .so if you are lucky enough that the developer did not used `proguard` chances are there you might end up looking the original code.Try the following 
[link for reverse engineering the apk](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the full source code, as not all information is preserved within the apk (comments, etc.) and many things are re-ordered (as there are jump instructions instead of `if`, `while`, `for`, ...). For native code, it is even harder.

If you plan to get the source of commercial applications, applications may even got obfuscated, e.g. additional information is cropped from the apk.

If you only need to change/read tiny bits, you might want to use [smali](https://code.google.com/p/smali/) (if the parts you wish to access are not native), it is also used by many tools; it produces a readable format from the android bytecode. The use of such tools is only legal if you are the author of the apk, have the authors permission or have a legal right to do so (one example is living in the European Union, you are then allowed to adjust software you have a license for to achieve interoperability even without explicit permission by the author if there is no other way to archive the interoperability you want).